# How to get a good light bokeh using compositor in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, light

How to improve quality of bokeh especially lights?

[image: https://i.imgur.com/2qAvxO1.jpg]]

Comment: share the blend file so we can help you better http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: the link https://www.mediafire.com/?9crrwp8hv3do73d